# Change QLPreviewController background color

Tags: ios, colors, background, qlpreviewcontroller

This is a simple question I ask you: How can I change the background of the QLPreviewController component?

I use it to present PDF files but it shows up with the scrollview pattern as the background
color:

```
[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]
```

I would like to change that background color but changing the view's `backgroundColor` attribute is not helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass it and make the change.  Something like this:

.h file:

```
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>

@interface MyQLPreviewController : QLPreviewController
```

.m file:

```
#import "MyQLPreviewController.h"

@implementation MyQLPreviewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  // make the change for example
}
```

Comment: Before actually asking here I tried all these kind of stuff: subclassed, changed in the did load, changed in the did appear.. nothing seems to work. https://skitch.com/elbryan/eb8g3/ios-simulator

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and ended up subclassing `QLPreviewController` and adding the following to its implementation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Find webview and set its subviews' background color to white
    [[self.view subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        [self setSubviewsBackgroundColor:view];

    }];
}
```

and

```
- (void)setSubviewsBackgroundColor:(UIView*)view{

    [[view subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {

            [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [[subview subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            }];
        }
        else [self setSubviewsBackgroundColor:subview];
    }];
}
```

Of course you'll likely want to change `[UIColor whiteColor]` and optimize the above code to suit your needs.

Comment: This works in iOS 5.1 but does not in iOS 6. I think they are not using an instance of UIWebView anymore. Still, even setting the background color to each instance of UIView's subview won't work.